# Neovim: Change Cursor Type for Insert Mode

Tags: neovim

I'm new to (Neo) Vim and I'm trying to find configurations that I like and learn from them.

Whenever I watch people code in vim/neovim, I notice that their cursor a thick box, same as when they're outside of Insert mode.

Basically, while in insert mode, my cursor is thin like this `|`, but I want to change it so that it's thick like it is when you're outside of insert mode.

I'm on the latest version of Neovim and I use Windows 10 if that's useful information.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that is possible with `guicursor` option, but whether what option takes effect also depends on your terminal, for example, using Windows Termianl.

This is a working setting to make cursor shape block in insert mode:

```
set guicursor=n-v-c-i:block
```

which means to make cursor shape block in **n**ormal, **v**isual, **c**ommand, and **i**nsert mode. For more details, please use `:h 'guicursor'`.

Comment: could you please suggest a lua workaround with chadrc.lua or some file in the custom directory.

Answer (score 5):

lua workaround
vim.opt.guicursor = "n-v-c-sm:block,i-ci-ve:ver25,r-cr-o:hor20"

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Neovim using Lua to show the block cursor in insert mode:

```lua
vim.opt.guicursor = "n-v-i-c:block-Cursor"
```

`n-v-i-c` - it defines all modes in which the block cursor will be used.

`n` - normal, `v` - visual, `i` - insert, `c` - command

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change that setting with [guicursor](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27guicursor%27). (For <s>Neo</s>Vim there is [termcap-cursor-shape](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#termcap-cursor-shape).)

But note that the two different cursor actually make sense: In normal mode you are always *on* a character (i.e. you can use `i` and `a` to produce different results), while in insert mode the curor must be *between* two characters.

Personally I think that it would just get confusing to have a blocky cursor in insert mode due to the reason above, but furthermore it would make it harder to distinguish the two modes too!

And for future reference, there is a dedicated stackexchange for [vi and vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: Counterpoint: it's really hard to spot a faint thin line in a screenful of code.

Comment: Agreed, but then again you'd usually be only using it while you're writing. But of course everyone should do what they like!